# Suppose $m \mid 2^p - 1$. Show that $m \equiv 1 \pmod {2p}$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I would like to get help with this proof:

> Let $p\ge3$ be a prime number, and let $m$ be a divisor of $2^{p}-1$, Prove that 
>   $m\equiv 1\ (mod\ 2p)$.

I thought about proving that $m=1\ mod\ p$, and $m=1\ mod\ 2$, and then by CRT prove that $m=1\ (mod\ 2p)$.

I am stuck after proving that $m=1\ (mod\ 2)$.

Comment: See $\#3$ of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#Theorems_about_Mersenne_numbers

Answer (score 1):

since $m$ is a divisor of $2^p-1$ then there exists an integer $k$ such that $mk = 2^p-1$

now since $p \geq 3$ is prime then we know by fermat's last theorem that $$2^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$  because obviously $\gcd(2,p)=1$ and so this implies that $p \mid2^{p-1} -1$ and hence there exists an integer $q$ such that $pq = 2^{p-1} -1$ and if we multiply by $2$ each side of the equation we get $2pq = 2^{p}-2$

But we already know that $mk = 2^{p}-1$ and so $2pq = mk -1$ and so we have that $mk \equiv 1 \pmod{2p}$ , can you get rid of the $k$ ?

Comment: How do you get rid of k?

Comment: i join to the question.. how to get rid of that k